# How can I install software without internet?

Tags: installation, offline

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

At this moment I have next situation:

I have 2 computers:

First computer with Windows 7 and connection to the internet;
Second computer with latest Ubuntu 11.10 and without connection to the internet.

and, my question next: How in this case I can install new packages on Ubuntu?

Comment: see this:[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/160286/how-to-install-programs-on-other-ubuntu-machines-without-using-the-internet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is rather a tricky situation if both the systems are remotely located from each other and cannot have network sharing (Internet sharing), And I have a tricky solution to your Problem.

Install Ubuntu 11.10 using Wubi installer on your windows 7 Machine. This way you will not alter your system in anyway.

Then install the following **Portable Software Center** on the Wubi install of Ubuntu.
Here is a way to install it.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/12/portable-software-center-create-custom.html

Download the software you need for your original Ubuntu PC & transfer the files using a Pen drive or External Hard Disk and Install. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that those two computers are located next to each other because otherwise this information would be meaning less.

Now to install packages on Ubuntu system, you have two options:
Share the Windows PC's internet connection with the one running Ubuntu. For this connect the two computers using a direct network cable or by using a router if you have one. Then setup you windows PC to share internet connection and change Ubuntu PC's network connection properties to assign it a manual IP and to use the Windows PC's ip as gateway. If you decide to use this method then I can provide more detailed info.

The second method would be to download packages and install them offline. There is a very good answer by Javier Rivera [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1002/6713), I am just copying it here for completeness sake:

"Check out [Keryx](http://keryxproject.org/), it's an offline repository manager- it lets you download updates and new programs (with dependencies) to your flash drive. Its interface is similar to synaptic but it works on a pendrive (don't need installation). Unfortunately, the GUI needs wxwidgets, which don't come preinstalled on ubuntu (they're cross-platform and installable from [here](http://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/#latest_stable) and ubuntu repository [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/InstallingOnUbuntuOrDebian)). It can only install software in a Ubuntu system, but you can download the updates or new packages in any Linux, Windows or OS/X.

Here you can find a [tutorial](http://crashsystems.net/2009/01/keryx-tutorial/)."