# Is it possible to install Ubuntu directly from and to the HDD?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I live a long way from stores. I'm in rural Eastern Cape South Africa. I downloaded Ubuntu but I don't have any blank DVD's. Can I copy it to my HDD and install from there?

Comment: Are you already running Linux with grub2?

Answer (score 2):

You can install from a hard drive, as long as it's not the hard drive you're installing Ubuntu in (you need a spare/external one).

The answers to [this questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291500/install-on-usb-external-hard-drive) explain how.

You can also [use a flashdrive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, it's possible. Yet it is quite a bit easier to use a DVD or USB pen drive. So, if you want to have the "simply works" experience you might expect from Ubuntu, try to get a DVD-R or a USB pen drive.

If you are still motivated to try the HDD boot method, read the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/index.html) for the **alternate** CD, at least the parts about installing from HDD. Since it's a guide for the alternate CD, it might be worth to also download the alternate CD instead of the normal Live-CD, to ensure that everything works as described.